# Time problems when delete and add documents to Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I created an app in Flutter and I try to refresh data in Firebase deleting the old documents and adding new ones. Deleting 100 documents (the entire collection) one by one takes me around 19.158398 seconds and adding 100 documents takes 17.511311. When I perform a refresh need to delete entire collection and after recreate it with new documents.
This is the way I delete all documents of the collection:

```
  QuerySnapshot qs = await Firestore.instance
    .collection('DOCUMENTS')
    .where('WS', isEqualTo: '${globals.qSN}')
    .limit(2)
    .getDocuments();
if (qs.documents.length > 0) {
  await Firestore.instance
      .collection('DOCUMENTS')
      .getDocuments()
      .then((snapshot) async{

    for (DocumentSnapshot doc in snapshot.documents) {
       await doc.reference.delete();
    }
  });
}
```

And this is the way I add documents:

```
for(var obj in object.data){

   await Firestore.instance
        .collection('DOCUMENTS')
        .add({
      'MT': '${obj.mt}',
      'CODE': '${obj.code}',
      'NAME': '${obj.name}',});}
```

Can you help me with any opinion about how to do it faster? Waiting 36 seconds is a little too much (in my opinion). I tried to find an option on my own in the last two weeks, but I got no result.

Comment: You can speed this up by batching the request. Rather than doing them one by one you should do all operation as one. 
I don't actually know how it works but I would start looking around this class `Firestore.instance.batch();`

Comment: At the end of the day, you deserved to be the winner. Deleting time: 0:00:00.757063 Insertion time: 0:00:00.008760

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to accelerate deleting documents from a client app.  What you're doing is as fast as it gets from a client's perspective.  The time is probably due to the latency and limited bandwidth between you and the servers hosting your database.

Consider instead writing some backend code on a server that's physically located closer to the region where the data is stored.  You could do this by writing a [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) HTTP trigger that your client code can call.  Be sure to deploy the trigger to the same Google Cloud region as your Firestore instance.

Comment: but a solution for adding documents?

Comment: If you have a new question or problem, please post it separately.

Comment: In my question you can see that I have time problems with deleting and adding.

Comment: I don't see how adding would be any different than deleting - put them both on the backend if possible.  If not possible, then you have to accept the delay.

Comment: I'll do some research about what you said and after if that is the fittest solution for my problem I will mark your answer as the correct one.

Comment: To be sure, you think that will speed up the processes?

Comment: Anything you can do to lower the latency between the client and server will improve the speed (especially putting them on the same network).  This is easy to try and benchmark for yourself.

Comment: I have Google Cloud Platform (GCP) resource location in us-central, but my project is used from the east part of Europe. Do you think that slow down the processes? And if you answer is yes, how much?

Comment: That's something you'll have to benchmark on your own.  I don't have any idea what the quality of the network is between you and the us-central1.

Comment: Thank you for your time.